# Задача с олимпиады

Tags: c++, алгоритм, оптимизация, олимпиада

> Необходимо написать программу, которая находит k-ое число по
> возрастанию в массиве A = <a1,a2,a3....an>. Массив А задаётся с
> помощью полинома P(x) = [image: введите сюда описание изображения],
> ai = P(i) mod 2021.
>
> Задано k и n.
>
> Пример:
>
> k = 1, n = 1, то ответ 169. k = 1, n = 10, то ответ 36.

Возможно ли оптимизировать вычисления, если да то как (варианта кроме как просто считать каждое число)? (ограничения k и n 4000000, время 1 секунда, память 256Мб). Возможно, следует использовать multiset,  это единственное, что приходит в голову.  Проблема переполнения типов решается преобразованием уравнения:

Из [image: 123x^3 +456x^2+789*x+822%2021] в [image: введите сюда описание изображения] после каждой операции делать взятие остатка по модулю 2021.

Comment: А вы не хотите считать A(n+1) исходя из A(n)? URL не дадите поиграться?

Comment: @Harry я думаю невозможно считать следующее исходя из предыдущего так как следующий элемент никак не зависит от предыдущего (после добавления нового элемента массив сортируется), а к URL у меня нет доступа, только бумажный вариант, как и к проверочной системе.

Comment: А что, в секунду не удается посчитать этот полином 4'000'000 раз?

Comment: @user7860670 не на всех языках, на python точно невозможно, а на c++ вперёд всего пройдёт, но я хочу знать есть ли решение которое работает быстрее простого подсчёта

Comment: Конечно есть, во время выполнения программы полином можно вообще не считать, а взять из готовой таблицы нужное количество значений, а затем их отсортировать.

Comment: Значения многочлена нужно вычислить 2021 раз. После чего они начнут повторяться по кругу. `a_(i+2021) = a_i`.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy и вправду повторяются, а почему так происходит?

Comment: Это свойство арифметических операций по модулю. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E

Comment: А зачем его сортировать?... k-й элемент можно найти куда быстрее...

Comment: @Harry, "k-ое число по возрастанию".

Comment: @Алёна, вы можете убедится руками что `P(x + 2021) = P(x) mod 2021`.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Да,  моя тестовая программа  говорит, что ваше предположение верно.

Comment: Тестовая программа тут не нужна. `(a + 2021) + b = a + b mod 2021`, `(a + 2021)b = ab mod 2021`, `(a+2021)^k = a^k mod 2021`. Этого достаточно чтобы доказать (в уме) что `P(x + 2021) = P(x) mod 2021`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy И что, для этого надо сортировать все? [`nth_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) уже не работает? :)

Comment: Сортировать вообще ничего не надо. Надо завести 2021 счётчик и заполнить их для `n` (с умом, то есть за 2021 или 4042 итерации). Затем надо их суммировать накопительно пока не получим `k`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Многочлен считаем по схеме Горнера. После каждого шага берём по модулю чтобы не было переполнения.

Про многочлен известно что `p(x + 2021) = p(x) mod 2021`. Поэтому считать его надо только `2021` раз.

`counts[y]` хранит количество раз когда `y = p(x), 1 <= x <= n`.

Функция `in_range(a, b, x)` считает сколько раз арифметическая прогрессия `x + k * modulo` попадает в полуинтервал `[a, b)`.

Для каждой прогрессии (их 2021 различных) многочлен считаем один раз, получаем `y`. `counts[y]` увеличиваем на число элементов прогрессии в интервале `[1, n]`.

Когда `counts` готов нужно последовательно вычитать его значения из `k`. Индекс на котором `k` станет не положительным - `k`-тое значение в отсортированной последовательности `a_i, 1 <= i <= n`.

```
#include <iostream>

const int modulo = 2021;

int p(int x) {
    int y = 123;
    y = (456 + x * y) % modulo;
    y = (789 + x * y) % modulo;
    y = (822 + x * y) % modulo;
    return y;
}

// number of {x + k * module} in half interval [a, b)
int in_range(int a, int b, int x) {
    return (b - x + modulo - 1) / modulo - (a - x + modulo - 1) / modulo;
}

int main() {
    int k;
    int n;
    if(!(std::cin >> k >> n)) {
        return 1;
    }

    int counts[modulo] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < modulo; ++i) {
        counts[p(i)] += in_range(1, n + 1, i);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < modulo; ++j) {
        k -= counts[j];
        if (k <= 0) {
            std::cout << j << '\n';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror fast.cpp
>
> echo 1 1 | ./a.out
> 169
>
> $ echo 1 10 | ./a.out
> 36
>
> $ echo 1 4000000 | ./a.out
> 5
>
> $ time echo 4000000 4000000 | ./a.out
> 2019
>
> real  0m0.002s
> user  0m0.000s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```